# Can someone improve my feeble understanding of feature maps and kernels?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I am taking the course and the extent in which we've discussed feature maps and kernels is as follows:

> **Given**
>
> [image]
>
> Obviously we cannot use linear regression.
>
> Instead we map it to a space where it becomes separable using a
> function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^k$
>
> Then do linear regression on that space. Then transform it back into a circular separator.
>
> For example, in this instance, because the shape of the separator is a circle, I might want to use the feature map $f(x) = (1, x_1, x_2, x_1x_2, x_1^2, x_2^2)$. After I transform all my data into this new space, perform linear regression on these data and yield some weight + bias $w, b$. Then $w^Tf(x)$ is my optimal classifier in the original space.

Ok, but I have many questions given this tiny exposure to feature maps and kernels,

1. What if you cannot visualize the data? How can you know what function $f$ to choose?
2. Even if you could visualize the data, the data could be arranged in a very weird fashion (i.e., only separable by a squiggle?). How can you choose $f$ so that it becomes separable in a higher dimension?

I just cannot see how people come up with this function $f$ when they cannot even see the data.